# Проблема при выводе ответа

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть задача: в файле 20 чисел,и надо вывести:

1.Количество всех троек (даже если дано число 333, то должна просчитаться каждая тройка)

2.Количество всех чисел , которые больше 10.

На языке Си решил за 10 минут, а вот на C++ не получается. Например-почему из файла выводятся все символы как они есть, а когда приводишь их к типу int , чтобы потом сравнить- выводится только первый символ? Прошу обьяснить на примере кода языка С++.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    const int mas_count = 20;
    string line;
    int three_count = 0, int_line[mas_count];
    string mas[mas_count];

    ifstream file_nums("numbers.txt");
    if (file_nums.is_open()) {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(file_nums, line))
        {       
            mas[i] = line;
            int_line[i] = stoi(mas[i]);

            cout << mas[i] << endl;
            cout << int_line[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //сюда не обращайте внимания
    for (int i = 0; i < mas_count; i++) {
        int_line = stoi(mas[i]);
        cout << int_line << endl;
        int_line = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int i = 0;

  while (!feof(f1))
  {
    i++;
    num = fgetc(f1);
    if (!feof(f1))
    {
      printf("%c", num);
      if (num == '3') n++;
    }
  };

  sum = 0;
  for (int j = 1; j < 16; j++)

    if (mas[j] > 10) {      
      sum = sum + 1;

    }
    else
    {

      sum = sum + 0;

    }
  fclose(f1);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\nВ тексте встречается %i раз цифра 3\n", n);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\nВ тексте  %i чисел больше за  10\n", sum);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Файл: numbers.txt

Содержимое: 1 3 5 8 12 13 16 20 23 24 27 30 33 35 36 40 42 43 45 49 50

Ответ должен выглядеть так:

1.Количество троек: 9

2.Чисел больше 10: 17

Comment: Приведите содержимое своего файла, ожидаемый вывод программы и фактический вывод программы.

Comment: изменил в описании

Comment: Вообще-то слоило бы привести не то, что должно вывести, а *ожидаемый вывод программы и фактический вывод*

Comment: на скрине есть, то что оно вывело

Comment: но походу, я не понял твоего вопроса...

Comment: видимо вас приводит в замешательство то, что `getline` читает сразу всю строку `1 3 5 8 12 13 16 20 23 24 27 30 33 35 36 40 42 43 45 49 50` на первом же шаге

Comment: я уже это решил, когда записал все числа в столбец. Короче новый вопрос: как считывать ПОСИМВОЛЬНО в C++? Сишным способом решил. Вот именно там, где while (getline(file_nums, line)) надо заменить на посимвоьльный способ

Comment: Покажите код на С, который делает то, что вам нужно. Думаю, так будет проще.

Comment: ну если посимвольно, то `char c{}; file_nums >> c; if(not file_nums.eof()) { делаем что-то с символом }`

Comment: Прикрепил код на С

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно посимвольное считывание.

Если сделан ввод из файла по уму - сразу чисел (например, с помощью `cin`), то нужно просто посчитать количество цифр-троек

```
while(n) {
   digit = n % 10;
   if (digit==3)
      count3++;
   n = n / 10; 
}
```

Если вводятся строки, то по каждой можно пройти, подсчитать символы-тройки